# Batch script to copy data base on current date & modified date?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need copy outlook data from users to my NAS server every 2 times/month on 1st & 14th and copy file at users log on to windows.

Copy from Source to NAS server.

This is my idea!

```
If (current date = 1 or 14) & (date modified at Source <> date modified at Des)
{
do your_batch_file.bat
}
else
   exit
```

Can somebody help me? Tks you very much!

Comment: where is outlook data? in client computers? and you need to send them to server too? or they're in you server and just need copy?

Comment: It's in client computers. I need copy file automatic on given date.

Comment: How do you know that the client computer will be powered on? What will happen if the computer is not available on exactly those dates?

Comment: A simple scheduled task to run a batch file on the 1st and 14th would be the easiest implementation.  If the computer is not turned on, on those days, the task can be set to run the task at the next available bootup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
wmic os get localdatetime | > nul findstr /b /r /c:"......01" /c:"......14" && (
    robocopy "c:\somewhere" "x:\saveddata" *.pst 
)
```

- `wmic` is used to retrieve the local date/time
- `findstr` with two regular expressions is used to determine if the day is `01` or `14`
- If `findstr` finds the search string, it will clear `errorlevel` and the conditional operator `&&` (execute next command if the previous one did not fail) will execute `robocopy`
- `robocopy` will copy the updated files (by default it only copies changed files) from source to target

But probably the best option is to declare a scheduled task to handle the date selection and start the copy operation.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Check if today we need to do a backup
    wmic os get localdatetime | > nul findstr /b /r /c:"......01" /c:"......14" && (

        rem Check if we have already done the backup
        robocopy "%temp%." "%temp%." flagFile /is /maxage:1 >nul 2>nul && (

            rem  Execute the backup
            robocopy "c:\somewhere" "x:\saveddata" *.pst

            rem And mark the backup as done
            >"%temp%\flagFile" type nul
        )
    )
```

A flag file is generated (in this sample in `temp` folder). To determine if the flag file is missing, it is an old file or it has been generated today, `robocopy /maxage:1` is used:

- If the file does not exist it can not be copied and `errorlevel` is 0
- If the file exists but it is an old file the `/maxage:1` excludes it from the copy and `errorlevel` is 0
- If the file exists but it has been generated today, the `/maxage:1` will not exclude it, it is selected for copy, but as source and target are the same it will be skipped and `errorlevel` will be 1

So, conditional execution operator `&&` (execute next command if the previous one did not fail) will start the backup and the creation of the flag file.

Comment: Thanks you for your suppor! but i just need copy at first users log on. Because if users log on again and files changed, the batch file will be run again.

Comment: Many thanks you, but you missed /b in updated code, otherwise robocopy will be excute every day!

Comment: @HuyTortoises, I see, It will not run every day but of course it will run when not needed. Answer updated, again.

Comment: Hi! Bother you again. I don't want display the patch of log files when i excute command /LOG:"your_patch\backup_log.txt" on command prompt.
This is my full code "robocopy "D:\Documents\Outlook Files" "\\192.168.0.6\OutlookFile\HUUHUY" *.pst /COPYALL /NJH /TEE /LOG:\\192.168.0.6\OutlookFile\HUUHUY\BACKUP_LOG.TXT"

Can U help me? Tks pro!

Comment: It's worked but it will not display percentage copied

Comment: @HuyTortoises, I don't see a way to have both options. If you only want to mask the log location, you can generate the log file localy (and show the local path) and then move the log to the target server.

Comment: Hey, bro! I have a problem. How to copy a root folder (source folder) to destination folder by robocopy? Tks very much!

Comment: @HuyTortoises, The problem are the quotes and the ending backslash that escapes the closing quote. You have at least three options: robocopy x:\ (no quotes), `robocopy "x:\\"` (doubled ending backslash) or `robocopy "x:\."` (self directory reference for the root folder). If you are using a variable then the last is probably the easier as you can use `robocopy "%source%."`